# Can a primary key in Cassandra contain a collection column?

Tags: cassandra

Can a primary key in Cassandra contain a collection column?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  first_name text,
  emails set<text>,
  description text

  PRIMARY KEY (first_name, emails)
);
```

Comment: There is a very easy way to figure out the answer for yourself: try pasting your CQL into cqlsh and see what Cassandra says.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Collection types cannot be part of the primary key, and neither can the counter type. You can easily test this yourself, but the reason might not be obvious.

Sets, list, maps are hacks on top of the storage model (but I don’t mean that in a negative way). A set is really just a number of columns with the same key prefix. To be a part of the primary key the value must be scalar, and the collection types aren’t.

Comment: Hey Theo, just want to thank you for your answer. I was very confused that I was able to do this in Big Table, but not in Cassandra, which is supposed to be based off of Big Table. We now are writing a layer on top of Cassandra to create the index table. You don't by any chance know of any databases (other than GAE's Big Table) that take care of this abstraction so we don't  have to, do you?

Comment: Sorry, too little information to answer that question meaningfully. You can probably model your data a little bit differently and make it work, but I don't know anything about your usecase so I can't really speculate. It looks a bit odd to me to have *all* of a user's e-mails in the primary key, because it would mean that you have to know them all to find a user...

Comment: Hey Theo, yes, looking back over the question, having the e-mails there does not make sense. At the time I was very confused about how to do queries against Cassandra and just grasping the idea that "queries" are always done against the primary key. The idea was to be able to search for a person based on their first name and one of their e-mails (not a real use case). In reality, a different row would have to be written to an index table for each single_email-username variant.

Comment: Perhaps the source of all the confusion is that traditional databases like PostgreSQL handle all of the indexing behind the scenes. It sounds like Cassandra offers only very low-level indexing and querying capabilities (a sorted key-value store) and excels at handling the server clustering. If using Cassandra for higher-level querying, we would need to have to build an indexing engine on top of it ourselves?

Comment: For some cases Cassandras built in indexes work well, but I believe that e-mails is one of the canonical examples for when it doesn’t (high cardinality is the dealbreaker). I usually end up building indexes myself. Every case is unique. The most important thing is to think about how you want to query the data, and *then* think about how to store it. Usually you work the other way around.

Answer (score 14):

It's been a while but as this is on first page in Google when you look for using a map in the primary key, I thought it was worth to update it.

Cassandra [now allows](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html) (I think since 2.1) to use a collection in a Primary Key provided it is *frozen*.

A *frozen* value serializes multiple components into a single value. Non-frozen types allow updates to individual fields. Cassandra treats the value of a frozen type as a blob. The entire value must be overwritten.

With frozen, the collection becomes essentially immutable not allowing for modifications in-place, therefore, becoming suitable for a Primary Key.

Here is an example using a frozen list.

```
CREATE TABLE test_frozen (
    app_id varchar,
    kind varchar,
    properties frozen <list<text>>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((app_id, kind), properties));
```

Since 2.1, Cassandra also allows to create an index on columns of type map, set or list - though that not's necessarily a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say no: because the collection is mutable, and you can't have a primary key that keeps changing in time.

Comment: Can we say that it's not a very  useful  primary key?

Comment: If I understand how Cassandra works correctly, the way that Cassandra is meant to be queried is by primary key?

Comment: @ChrisGerken that's right. it wouldn't be a unique identifier, defeating the whole purpose of a primary key

Comment: @ChrisDutrow Precisely, a key-value database with no useful keys is meaningless

Comment: If I understand correctly, its a little more than a key-value database, in that you can use greater than and less than queries and order results?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow yes, it's possible to perform range queries on keys (with appropriate partitioner configuration). Same comments apply though - an ever-changing key is no good

Comment: @Óscar López - Still trying to piece this all together. What I'm ultimately trying to do is query against list values. This is possible using Big Table, which Cassandra is supposed to be similar to?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Big Table - but I guess you can perform similar queries against sets in cassandra, not necessarily primary keys

Comment: @Óscar López - Ah ok, would this be done using a secondary index?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow not necessarily. Why don't you take a look at the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/using/collections)? It's a good resource ;)

Comment: @Óscar López - Been looking at the documentation all day today and all day yesterday. It talks a lot about how to do specific things, but not about how to use it for use cases like this.